# Can I read a notes.ini parameter from a different server?

Tags: lotus-domino

I wonder if I am able to open a server connection in an Agent running on server A to access the notes.ini of server B. I want to read check for a parameter in that notes.ini. Is that possible via coding?
I am aware of session.getEnvironment methods but they access the notes.ini of the server where the Agent is running on (or the Notes client).
Any ideas?

**Used the solution from Egor:**

```
/**
 * checks for notes.ini value for
 * @return
 * @throws NotesException
 */
private boolean checkNoSessionInfo(String serverName) {
    boolean result = false;
    try {
        String console = session.sendConsoleCommand(serverName, "show config *");
        result = console.contains("LOG_DISABLE_SESSION_INFO=1");
    } catch (NotesException e) {
        oli.logErrorEx(e, "Could not check if server's user session info was disabled", OpenLogItem.SEVERITY_MEDIUM, null);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Works like a charm! :-)

Thank you all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add the Server A to Trusted Servers of Server B server document in names.nsf (and maybe few other fields on security tab). After I'd just use Session.sendConsoleCommand method (use command "show config *". See documentation for reference: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_SENDCONSOLECOMMAND_METHOD_SESSION_JAVA.html

Comment: Yep, this works. If you want to get f.e. Notes\Data folder you would call `Session.sendConsoleCommand("Server1/ACME", "show config Directory")`

Comment: Yes, confirmed - works great. I updated my question and added my solution.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think you really need the Trusted Servers permission for this. I think the only case where that permission is needed is when an agent on ServerA needs to access a database on ServerB - in which case ServerB's server document must list ServerA in the Trusted Servers field.

Comment: As a side note, the output of the `show config Directory` command will show up in the server logs. To prevent this prefix the command with an exclamation mark, like this `!show config Directory`. This way only the command itself will show up (also, see the `Log_Console` INI setting).

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of issues with this:

1. You would need a NotesSession object of server B on server A which is not possible.
2. Unfortunately you can not execute agent on server B from server A, it just does not work:
   `02.03.2016 10:51:05   Agent 'TestRunAgent' error: Cannot access foreign servers when running on a server)`
3. Your best bet would be a HTTP call from server A to server B, this way the server B agent can return HTML with required property.

You can return simple HTML body by using `print` keyword, it conveniently prints to HTTP response.

Comment: Yes, found that, too - will check!

Comment: A Java Agent can open a remote Session object (over DIIOP) and run code in the context of the remote server. However, DIIOP needs to be setup on the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, I think it should be possible to do this by calling a web service, custom REST servlet or XAgent on server B. That would return the information you need.

Comment: It's not a web app and no HTTP running - will try sendConsoleCommand method

Comment: Maybe an agent can't create an HTTP session using e.g. ApacheHTTPClient classes if HTTP isn't running on the server A then. It certainly wouldn't help if HTTP isn't running on server B.